# using (char*) in switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, strcmp

I am new in C programming language and have an (if statement) and need to transfer it into switch statement.
My problem is that I have a field named (node_kind) of char* type and I compare it's content in the if statement using (strcmp) but I don't know how to do that in the switch statement.
Would you plz tell me how ?
Here is a short quote of my program

```
if (strcmp(node->node_kind, "VAR_TOKEN_e") == 0) 
    job = visitor->visitjob_VAR_TOKEN; 
if (strcmp(node->node_kind, "INT_e") == 0) 
    job = visitor->visitjob_int; 
if (strcmp(node->node_kind, "BOOL_e") == 0) 
    job = visitor->visitjob_bool;
```

Comment: If the is homeworo I would look at enimerations.  If not go with Paul R.'s answer and find a way not to hardcode this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gperf ([website](http://www.gnu.org/s/gperf/)) to generate a perfect hash, which turns strings into integers.  You'll have something like this:

In your header file:

```
enum {
    STR_VAR_TOKEN_e,
    STR_INT_e,
    STR_BOOL_e
};
int get_index(char *str);
```

In your gperf file:

```
struct entry;
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"
struct entry { char *name; int value; };
%language=ANSI-C
%struct-type
%%
VAR_TOKEN_e, STR_VAR_TOKEN_e
INT_e, STR_INT_e
BOOL_e, STR_BOOL_e
%%
int get_index(char *str)
{
    struct entry *e = in_word_set(str, strlen(str));
    return e ? e->value : -1;
}
```

In your switch statement:

```
switch (get_index(node->node_kind)) {
case STR_VAR_TOKEN_e: ...
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C you can only use integer literal constants in switch case labels.

For the code example above though, you ought to think about using a "data driven" approach rather than hard-coding all this stuff into the program logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a switch statement for this.

But you can speed up execution of your code somewhat by using "else if" instead of "if" for the second and third conditionals.

Comment: Why would this execute faster?

Comment: Because in the OP's code, if the first if statement turns out to be true, he'll carry on and do the strcmps for all the other cases which we already know will be false.  If else will short-circuit that.